# Bootstrap jQuery, how to show hidden DIV when child form fields are populated AND clear them when DIV is hidden?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

Pretty straightforward, I want to create a form that has a hidden section of "extra" search options. i.e. I don't want to burden the user with the extra fluff if they don't need it so I want to be able to:

- create a hidden div to hold all the extra fields (this works)
- show/hide that field on a button click (this works)
- clear the fields in the hidden div IF they are populated AND IF the div is hidden again (not implemented)
- automatically have the div visible if any of the form fields in the div are populated, i.e. on a page refresh or form submission. [ when the search is submitted, the fields get repopulated with the last search so the user can search again, if one of the extra fields is populated, I need the div to be visible so they know what they are searching]
- have it be re-usable without specifying individual field names ~ there are 3 nearly identical forms on the same page

Here is part of the form:

```
<div class="row" style="display:none;" id="stainless-extra-options">

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label for="maxlen">Max Length</label>
        <input name="maxlen" type="text" id="maxlen"  value="[[!+formdata.maxlen]]" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label for="maxwid">Max Width</label>
        <input name="maxwid" type="text" id="maxwid" value="[[!+formdata.maxwid]]" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label for="minlen">Min Length</label>
        <input name="minlen" type="text" id="minlen"  value="[[!+formdata.minlen]]" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group col-sm-3">
        <label for="minwid">Min Width</label>
        <input name="minwid" type="text" id="minwid" value="[[!+formdata.minwid]]" class="form-control input-sm" />
    </div>

</div>



<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <button type="submit" name="search" id="search" value="search" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block">Search Stainless</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block reset">New Search</button>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
        <button type="button" name="expand-stainless" id="expand-stainless" value="expand-stainless" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary btn-block toggle-extra-options" 
        data-target="#stainless-extra-options">More Options</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$( ".toggle-extra-options" ).click(function() {

  var target_selector = $(this).attr('data-target');
  var $target = $(target_selector);

  console.log('clicked ' + target_selector);

  if ($target.is(':hidden')){console.log('target hidden');
    $target.show( "slow" );
    $(this).html('Less Options');
  }else{console.log('target visible');
    $target.hide( "slow" );
    $(this).html('More Options');
  }

  console.log($target.is(':visible'));    

});
```

Here is a bootply of the bits that work so far: [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/b7uJwpLdC9)

I'd also like to get rid of the "slide in from the left" animation somehow... don't know why it's doing that!

Comment: what do the extra fields look like?  could you add them as data-extra1 .. extra5?  or is it more complex than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear all hidden fields on hide, instead of

```
$target.hide( "slow" );
```

do this:

```
$target.hide( "slow", function() {
    $target.find('input').val('');
});
```

To display the hidden fields on initial page load if any of them contain a filled-in value, add this to your code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( ".toggle-extra-options" ).each(function() {
        var target_selector = $(this).attr('data-target');
        var $target = $(target_selector);
        var show = false;
        $target.find('input').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != '') show = true;
        });
        if (show) $target.show();
    }); 
});
```

If you want a nicer animation effect, try jQuery's .slideUp() and .slideDown() instead of .show( "slow" ) and .hide( "slow" ).

Comment: This is almost perfect! thanks! One thing though, There are three forms stacked on the same page each with one of these hidden extra options fields. if we show the hidden div in one form, populate one of the fields then submit it, all the forms will show the hidden fields. We have three buttons with the 'toggle-extra-options' class, but each has a different data-target, I'm not sure why this would be happening. [it should show only the hidden fields in the form that was submitted AND had a field populated.

Comment: Ignore my last, the script I have processing the form is repopulating the hidden form fields & 'legitimately' showing them. By dumping some console logging I can see that this will work perfectly once I touch up the PHP :)